# facebook pixel conversation for the registration form

Tags: javascript, facebook, event-tracking

I want to put the fb pixel on the page and then use the conversion pixel to track everyone who is actually filling out the form

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '');
fbq('track', "PageView");
fbq('track', 'Lead');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1740955919461347&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

I have been using this html form:

```
<form id="contactform" action method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <input class="btn-blue" type="button" value="submit" id="submit" onclick="fbq('track', 'Lead')">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It takes all the viewer pixelize by facebook.I just need to track who complete the registration form.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a form:
http://codepen.io/jahid-webdev/pen/RGNKqE

And I just need to track the vistor who fill up the registration form.Can you please help me

Comment: I need to track the visitor using the standard Lead event who fill up the form

Comment: Thank you Jaromanda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrate the pixel on the registration complete view/page.

Your form does an HTTP **POST** request to handle and save things server side.
After your server has finished, there would be an redirect to this side I think. Otherwise we need to see more of the javascript or backend (php?) code ...

Comment: Then you have check the return value of the mail function, it's an bool which means it should be true if your mail is sent.

[link](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php)

Comment: The mail sent if i use valid mail address. Now i need to track those who sent the mail

Comment: Alright, do you build the form within a framework or from scratch? I ask this because if you use a framework, you have to return a new view with the base tracking inside, otherwise it would be the simplest way to send the form via ajax and put the response with something like jquery in your code again. If the ajax is complete, you can then call the tracking.

Comment: I have just used the php mail function and no framework with it

Comment: I am a novice in javascript

Comment: Look at the high rated answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)